# Why does mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition crash with NPE?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have a class called `ContactListFragment` to get user to select phone number from their contact book. My adapter is a cursor adapter as follows

```
private class ContactsAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
…

@Override
        public int getSectionForPosition(int i) {
            if (getCursor() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(i);
        }
...
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException at the line `return mAlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(i)`. I am not sure what constitutes enough information in this context, so I am including the stack trace below. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? My alphabet are all uppercase but I am using API 11 as opposed to API 14, so that I cannot use `android:textAllCaps` in

```
<style name="addressHeader" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

Here is the alphabet

```
<string name="alphabet">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</string>
```

For reference, I am using the ContactListFragment from the Google Tutorial as guide. The only difference to my knowledge is the API levels I mention.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.AlphabetIndexer.compare(AlphabetIndexer.java:128)
    at android.widget.AlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(AlphabetIndexer.java:265)
    at com.company.app.fragments.ContactsListFragment$ContactsAdapter.getSectionForPosition(ContactsListFragment.java:801)
    at android.widget.FastScroller.getThumbPositionForListPosition(FastScroller.java:648)
    at android.widget.FastScroller.onScroll(FastScroller.java:458)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1358)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1707)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2141)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1003)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:469)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:469)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:469)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:469)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1895)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1715)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1010)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I see `ContactsAdapter.getSectionForPosition(ContactsListFragment.java:801)` in your logcat, but you post the method `getPositionForSection` ?!?

Comment: Thanks. I edited. both methods are exactly the same in structure, so I copied and pasted the wrong one.

Comment: and what is in this line of `ContactsListFragment.java:801`?

Comment: 801 is `return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(i);`

Comment: I have the same problem when I use Android `4.4.2`. For `4.4.4` it works great. I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because my cursor data had `null` into his columnIndex that I passed in second param of `AlphabetIndexer`.

You can use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor))` to debug.